# What is the maximum emails that can be expanded in and EWS Distribution list?

Tags: soap, outlook, exchangewebservices

In our application we use the EWS SOAP based api to expand Distribution lists.

In our testing when we request an expand above ~5500 we get an error stating that the

`ErrorMessage: "Response exceeds 1 MB size limit. Please modify your EWS request."`

Does anyone have a strategy on how to count the number of emails in a distribution list programatically? sounds like we are requesting for too many users/emails

Comment: 1 MB is the limit a response can be within Outlook addin you will get that error with any request that creates a large response. If its for Office365 maybe look at the Graph to pull information about the groups directly

Comment: Appreciate the response! Unfortunately it seems if you use graph that you need an admin approved permission. i would need access to all of their groups. Admin based approval has been denied by business.

From my testing as well the dynamic distribution lists do not show up when i search for all groups using graph